# Webpack LESS-Loader, Keep LESS Variable unchanged

Tags: javascript, webpack, less, themes, less-loader

I am using **Webpack 3** with **LESS-loader**. I know **LESS-Loader compiles the less file to CSS** file. But As I am new to Webpack, I don't know h**ow can I keep the LESS variable as it is and later modify it with JavaScript**.

I had used **ModifyVar** and passed it using webpack and it worked. However I want to **dynamically change the CSS**. Like Server will send me the path of Theme CSS (Updated Variable values) and I will import it using LESS + JS.

Any help will be appreciated. I had search over Google as well as StackOverflow, In case of duplicate please comment and give me the correct URL.

Comment: the compilation from less to sass happens at build time. You could compile that sending a http request and return the bundle with http as well. Be prepared because that is too much of a burden

Comment: Yes, but once the bundling is done, I can not update the CSS Variables. I need solution post bundling. Thanks.

Comment: Well, there is none. You can't do that post-bundle.